# Error connect with MySql Database in web server

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse

I am connecting to external database from my android application in Eclipse. it is MySQL Server using PHP and JSON.
The problem is that when I test from localhost everything goes right, but to give the URL of the web server the application is closed.

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static String mensaje_bienvenida = "com.example.AndroidConnectingToPhpMySQL.MESSAGE";
Button btnLogin;
EditText txtNick;
EditText txtClave;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
//private static String url_usu = "http://10.0.2.2/SistemaMedico/verificarusuario.php";
//ip orange ventas: 207.58.133.155
private static String url_usu = "http://www.orangeventas.com/SistemaMedico/verificarusuario.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_USUARIO = "usuario";
private static final String TAG_NICK = "nick";
private static final String TAG_CLAVE = "clave";
private static final String TAG_IDUSU = "idusu";
private static final String TAG_IDPER = "idper";
private static final String TAG_NOMBRE = "nombre";
private static final String TAG_SEXO = "sexo";

String nick;
String clave;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    /*StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);*/


    //Le damos a las variables las propiedades de sus respectivos controles
            btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
            txtNick = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nick);
            txtClave = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.clave);

            //Evento clic del botón
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(txtNick.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
                    {
                        if(txtClave.getText().toString().trim().length() >= 6)
                        {
                            nick = txtNick.getText().toString().trim();
                            clave = txtClave.getText().toString().trim();
                            new ValidarUsuario().execute();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreenActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Mensaje");
                            builder.setMessage("Ingrese Clave");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);                             
                            builder.create();
                            builder.show();
                            txtClave.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {                   
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreenActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Mensaje");
                        builder.setMessage("Ingrese Nick de Usuario");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
                        builder.create();
                        builder.show();
                        txtNick.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

}

class ValidarUsuario extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    /*
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreenActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }*/

    protected String doInBackground(String...params)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int success;
                try
                {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NICK, nick));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CLAVE, clave));

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_usu, "POST", params);
                    Log.d("Validando Usuario", json.toString());

                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        JSONArray usuarioObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USUARIO);
                        JSONObject usuario = usuarioObj.getJSONObject(0);
                        /*
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(mensaje_bienvenida, usuario.getString(TAG_NOMBRE));*/

                        String genero = "BIENVENIDO";
                        final String nusu = usuario.getString(TAG_NOMBRE);
                        //mensaje_bienvenida = nusu;

                        if(usuario.getString(TAG_SEXO)=="F")
                        {
                            genero = "BIENVENIDA";
                        }

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreenActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Mensaje");
                        builder.setMessage(genero + " " + usuario.getString(TAG_NOMBRE));

                        /*
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Log.i("Dialogo", "Aceptado");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(mensaje_bienvenida, nusu);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });*/

                        builder.create();
                        builder.show();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(mensaje_bienvenida, nusu);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreenActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Mensaje");
                        builder.setMessage("Intente nuevamente");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
                        builder.create();
                        builder.show();
                        txtClave.setText("");
                        txtClave.requestFocus();
                    }

                }
                catch(JSONException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

using the debug error comes up:
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file InvocationTargetException.class.

But I repeat that from localhost runs all ok.
I need help. Thank you.

Comment: The error you quoted above isn't the cause of your problem.  Try reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902391/error-message-the-source-attachment-does-not-contain-the-source-for-the-file-lis), it'll give you some background into the error.

Comment: what the heck are you doing here?  protected String doInBackground(String...params)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {